# Kruskal algorithm on graph, how can this be right?

Tags: kruskals-algorithm

I have noticed this picture while viewing a website.

In my opinion, it is wrong,

As you can see ES, GI, DF, EF are given as the first 4 in this picture.

Shouldn't it be ES, GI, DF, DS?

It was supposed to be in lexical order, then why is it marked as correct answer?
What am I missing?
[image: link]

PS, this was one of the exam questions on my university.

Comment: It does seem to be incorrect, but this also looks like online homework, and I've had my fair share of such things being erroneous

Comment: I see, I shouldn't have assumed it was correct just because the system says so then.

Comment: I'm leaning very much so towards a system error, but I'd ask your professor as well.